# What's difference between primitive and wrapper class in JPA (Hibernate) column mappings?

Tags: java, jpa, wrapper, primitive

For instance, there’s an integer column in a database table.
Then in java model, it can be mapped both as **primitive int** and **Integer**.
My question is what's difference between the int and Integer in this case? And performance concern?
Thanks!

Comment: of course, I know that it will occur an exception when primitive int meets null value in database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to avoid using primitives. This is especially true for the Id attribute. This makes it possible to detect a not yet set value by testing for `null`. If using Java 5 or above, auto-boxing takes away the pain (and is not a performance concern). But also for other attributes. As pointed out by @skaffman, primitives are not suitable for nullable columns and I prefer the code to be as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You've already mentioned the difference - `Integer` can be `null`, `int` can't. So if your database column is nullable, then you should use `Integer`.

As for performance, I wouldn't worry about it. Modern VMs are very good at that sort of thing.