# JoiningTables using jpa and hibernate problem is mulitmapping failed

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jpa

I just started learning java ee two months ago and I am struggling in some parts as showing below. 
I have three entity classes for a booking system and struggling in running the project after I had done some logic:

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name="booking")
     public class Booking implements Serializable {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int reservationId;
     private String stateroomType;
     private double totalAmount;
     private int totalGuests;   
     private int shipId;
     private int passId;

  //Joining Tables
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="passId")
  private Passenger passenger;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="shipId")
  private Cruise cruise;

    @Entity
     @Table(name = "shipcruise")
    public class Cruise implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int cruiseId;
    private String cruiseName;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private Timestamp destination;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "passengers")
    public class Passenger implements Serializable{

    @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int passengerId;
    private String userName;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String postalCode;
    private String password;
```

When I run my project I get this error message:

**Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [booking.SHIPID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[cruise]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.springmvc.jpa.booking.Booking --> [DatabaseTable(booking)])
Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [booking.PASSID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[passenger]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.springmvc.jpa.booking.Booking --> [DatabaseTable(booking)])**

.................................................................................................

I understand that there is a problem in the mapping and I have made some research about it but still can not get the idea of how to solve it or how to make the relationship between the entity classes. Can anyone help me figure  out the problem and solve it.

Database tables:

```
      CREATE TABLE `booking` (
     `reservationId` int NOT NULL,
     `stateroomType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `totalGuests` int NOT NULL,
     `totalAmount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
     `passId` int DEFAULT NULL,
     `shipId` int DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`reservationId`),
      KEY `passId` (`passId`),
      KEY `shipId` (`shipId`),
      CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`passId`) REFERENCES 
      `passengers` (`passengerId`),
      CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`shipId`) REFERENCES 
      `shipcruise` (`cruiseId`)
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

      CREATE TABLE `passengers` (
     `passengerId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `userName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `password` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
     `firstname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
     `lastname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
     `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    `postalCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `country` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`passengerId`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
   COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `shipcruise` (
   `cruiseId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `CruiseName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `shipName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startDate` date NOT NULL,
  `endDate` date NOT NULL,
   `destination` timestamp NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`cruiseId`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.
In the entity Booking, you defined two fields that point to the same column in database.

     private int shipId; and  

 @JoinColumn(name="passId")
  private Passenger passenger;

When you do not specify the name of the column, JPA uses the attribute name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am confused about these relationships. Can you please clear that with an example. I have the shipId and the passId in the database joined to the booking table.

Comment: My bad. I copy and paste the incorrect property. You have the   
  ManyToOne
  JoinColumn(name="shipId")
  private Cruise cruise; 

that is the same as:  private int shipId;

Comment: I was trying to make the joining in this way but it gave an error so I had to declare the shId and passId in the booking entity class.

Comment: I get this error message::: Join column "shipId" cannot be resolved on table "booking"

Comment: I am doing joining in the database and I am repeating the joining in the booking entity class. Does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booking entity.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="booking")
 public class Booking implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer reservationId;
 private String stateroomType;
 private double totalAmount;
 private int totalGuests;   

 //Joining Tables
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="passId")
 private Passenger passenger;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="shipId")
 private Cruise cruise;
```

Cruise entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shipcruise")
public class Cruise implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer cruiseId;
private String cruiseName;
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalDate endDate;
private Timestamp destination;
```

Passengers entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "passengers")
public class Passenger implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer passengerId;
private String userName;
private String firstname;
```

In you code, you have:

```
 private int shipId;
 private int passId;
```

and below, you have:

```
  //Joining Tables
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="passId")
  private Passenger passenger;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="shipId")
  private Cruise cruise;
```

When, you do not use, @Column or @JoinColumn, the eclipse-link will use the field name, so, in this case, you will have 2 java properties that point to same column.

@JoinColumn does the dirty work for you(reference the other entity that references the SQL table), that is why we use JPA.

I changed the fields that represent primary key from int to Integer class.
You can find why here: [What's difference between primitive and wrapper class in JPA (Hibernate) column mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565352/whats-difference-between-primitive-and-wrapper-class-in-jpa-hibernate-column)

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot